# How to pass and invoke method references in Java

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

Let's say I have a class called `Server`, and I would like to allow others to write `Plugins` for it. Say `Plugin` is an Interface that extends `Runnable` and adds a single method: `void init(...)`. It is the job of a plugin to collect data and send it to the server. When the time comes to send data to the server, however, how does it do this? Coming from C and C++ I am looking for a thinking along the lines of a function pointer. It seems to be possible in Java though I have not found examples outside the Java Standard Class Library.

How do I pass a method reference to the `init` method such that it can be stored by the `Plugin`, and then how do I invoke the method whenever the Plugin wants to send data? For now say that the desired Server method is: `void sendData(Integer data)`.

For example:

```
// Inside Server
Plugin p = new PluginImplementation();
p.init(this::sendData);    

// Plugin init
public void init(?? sendMethod) {
    storedSendMethod = sendMethod;
    // ...
}

// Plugin run
public void run() {
    // ...
    storedSendMethod(x) // Sends data to server
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `java.util.function.Function` we can pass a function as an argument to a method, and then use `apply()` to apply it to the relevant arguments. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class FunctionDemo {

    // we will pass a reference to this method
    public static Integer square(Integer x) {
        return x * x;
    }

    // this method accepts the function as an argument and applies it to the input: 5
    public static Integer doSomething(Function<Integer, Integer> func) {
        return func.apply(5);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // and here's how to use it
        System.out.println(doSomething(FunctionDemo::square)); // prints 25
    }   
}
```

Additional version with multiple parameters (passed as an array):

```
public static Integer sum(Integer[] x) {
    Integer result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        result += x[i];
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(doSomething(Play::sum, arr));
}

public static Integer doSomething(Function<Integer[], Integer> func,
                                  Integer[] arr) {        
    return func.apply(arr);
}
```

Comment: Is this extendable to methods with multiple parameters? (Without making a wrapper class). I had a quick look at the docs and it seems to only allow two template types. I don't mind using a wrapper if I have to.

Comment: @Ephemera sure, see the example I just added.

Comment: @Ephemera: If you are talking about the [builtin function types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/package-summary.html), there are only predefined `interface`s  with up to two parameters, but there is no problem in creating your own [functional interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

Answer (score 2):

If the method is `void sendData(Integer data)` that corresponds to a consumer that takes an Integer and returns a void which is covered by the built in `Consumer<Integer>` interface which has an `accept(Integer)` method that will invoke your function when called.

So your code will look like this:

```
public void init(Consumer<Integer> sendMethod) {
    storedSendMethod = sendMethod;
    // ...
}

// Plugin run
 void run() {
    // ...
    storedSendMethod.accept(x) // Sends data to server
   // ...
}
```

As a sidenote, having an `init` method is probably a bad Java design.  you are better moving the initialization to the constructor if possbile

```
Plugin p = new PluginImplementation( this::sendData);
```

Comment: Can this be extended to accept multiple parameters (without making a wrapper class)? I did think that about `init`, but I have it there for the moment to adhere to another design I'm working with.

Comment: `Consumer#accept()` only takes 1 parameter.  But there is also a `BiConsumer` that takes 2.  If you need more than that, you can always make your own interface or use an already existing one

Answer (score 1):

In java, you do it with a callback,
This is your callback interface,

```
public interface SendCallback {
    public void doSend(Object toSend);
}
```

This is the plugin interface, All plugin must implement this interface

```
public interface Plugin extends Runnable {
    public void init(SendCallback callback);
}
```

This is the Server's code.

```
public class Server {

    Plugin plugin;

    SendCallback callback = new SendCallback() {
        public void doSend(Object toSend) {
                // logic to send object 'toSend'
        }
    }

    public Server() {
        plugin = new MyPlugin();
        plugin.init(callback);
    }

}
```

This is your plugin implementation.

```
public class MyPlugin implements Plugin {
    SendCallback callback = null;
    Object x = null;

    public void init(SendCallback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    public void run() {
        x = "Somthing"; // initialize the x object
        callback.doSend(x);
    }
}
```

You will notice, the server define the callback implementation.
The plugin will invoke the callback's method doSend.

I hope, this helps

Answer (score 0):

There is method reference in Java 8, however you can just pass a whole object and call its sendData() method.   In a 'plug-in' situation, using interfaces for each helps the plugin and the server have 'looser' coupling.

```
public interface Server {
    void setData(...);
}

public class MyPlugin implements plugin {

   private Server server;   

   void init(Server s )  {
       this.server = s;
   }

   void run() {
      ...
      this.server.setData(...);
      ...
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface Server{
  ...
  void sendData(String message);
}
```

Plugin doesn't need a function reference, you can use the Server interface for informing Plugin to know about that method.

```
class PluginX implements Plugin{
    ...
    private Server server;
    void init(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public void run() {
    // ...
        server.sendData(x) // Sends data to server
    // ...
```

}
    }